# Invalid X-CSRF-Token request header using fetchAPI and Drupal as decoupled back-end

Tags: reactjs, drupal, httprequest, fetch-api, csrf-protection

First of all, I am a starting developer. I apologize for making possible misconceptions.

I am trying to make a Reactjs application which communicates with a decoupled Drupal 8 back-end by using fetchAPI.

I want to make an authentication system by using session cookies. Getting the cookie from the Drupal site, and setting it in the browser works fine. I can include the cookie in HTTP requests. However, in addition to the cookie, Drupal also wants a 'x-csrf-token' to be included in the HTTP request header. This token can be acquired with a HTTP GET request to the Drupal site. So when a user logs in, I request both the cookie and the x-csrf-token, and I store the token in React's application state using Redux.

Now on the POST request I am trying to make, I get the token from the Redux store and include it in the HTTP request using the 'X-CSRF-Token' header. This gives me a 403 error with the following response: 'X-CSRF-Token request header is invalid'. The exact same request in combination with getting the cookie and token works fine in postman, so I do not know why I am getting this error in the browser.

I tried multiple browsers and different formats for the token, but I still can not get this to work.

(Note: I am using RESTful webservices from Drupal core with cookie authentication enabled.)

Getting the X-CSRF-Token:

```
export function getCsrfToken() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    fetch("http://drupalsite.local/rest/session/token", {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_CSRF_TOKEN,
          payload: token
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
}
```

The POST request:

```
export function post(name, csrfToken) {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    title: [
      {
        value: name
      }
    ],
    type: [
      {
        target_id: "test"
      }
    ]
  });

  return function(dispatch) {
    fetch("http://drupalsite.local/node", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken
      }),
      body: data
    })
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: POST_DATA_CORE_REST,
          payload: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
}
```

[HTTP headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue80H.png)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2976542 seems possibly relevant

Comment: I do not think it is relevant for my question, because I am sure I have the right token. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: In your HTTP headers, your request host header is drupalql.local, yet the domain in your code is drupalsite.local, and your origin is localhost:3000. Wonder if these mismatches could have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into a similar issue, but maybe not. I was searching for for awhile and this post kept coming up so I though I add an answer just incase anyone else stumbles on this.

It turns out that the X-CSRF-Token key was getting multiple values appended to it after the first fetch call. For example:

```
 1. x-csrf-token: wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY
 2. x-csrf-token: wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY, wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY
 3. x-csrf-token: wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY, wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY, wisHtEWaMVIXMe87Rxm5-aTI_M-FdR_pbE4XBZB50cY
```

The multiple values triggered the 403 error. I resolved this problem by first checking if the key existed. For example:

```
let headerCSRF = headers.get('X-CSRF-Token'); 
if ( !headerCSRF ) {  
  options.headers.append('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken); 
}
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution but it worked for me. This is related to the tutorial on Drupalize.

Comment: In my case I am sure I only assign one value to the token, so I think you ran into another issue. Thanks for sharing your answer.